# What happened to the debts of 456?

Tags: plot-explanation, squid-game

**Attention, massive spoilers ahead.**

In one of the early episodes we see that the main character is hunted by some gangsters because of his debts.
They tell him, that if he doesn't pay his debts they will sell some of his organs.
A year after the squid games we are told that the main character did not touch any of the prize money except the 10000 Won and is living a life like before the games.

Now I wonder how he could do this without paying his debts? I don't think the gangsters would leave him alone if he doesn't pay his debts.

Did I miss something here? Did he pay his debts from some other money? Or did he pay his debts from the prize money but it is not mentioned in the talk with the bank-employee? Or is it just not mentioned because the creators saw no relevance for the story?

Comment: One of the weak points of the show. How does he pay rent that entire year? How does he pay for food? Etc. Doesn't he need to pay for a funeral for his mother? Doesn't he need to pay her hospital bills? Maybe there's a translation error and perhaps he "barely" touched his winnings, maybe only taking the necessary money?

Comment: A possible argument, though unconfirmed, is that he used mibir amounts of the money, but the accrued interest during that year canceled out the money he used.